# WIFI problem UBUNTU 19.10 DELL E6430

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

Wifi is working great, after reboot.
Problem is when I close cover of my laptop. 
After I open laptop cover again sometimes working. It's randomly

In Normal:

```
[   27.129253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control 
[   29.467614] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm 
[   32.221824] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled 
[   32.221825] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled 
[   32.221826] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled [   32.221827] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN, REV=0xB0 
[   32.258241] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs' 
[   33.650391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0 
[   51.776618] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0 
[   52.078680] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

When it's stopped:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mikewen@mikewen:~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist.conf              blacklist-modem.conf         intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-firewire.conf     blacklist-oss.conf           iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf
mikewen@mikewen:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[17978.810481] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17979.116785] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17982.337623] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending REPLY_SCAN_ABORT_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[17982.337633] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 25 write_ptr 26
[17982.586081] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 18.168.6.1
[17982.586416] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | OK                         
[17982.586417] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uPc
[17982.586419] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink1
[17982.586420] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[17982.586421] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[17982.586422] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[17982.586424] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[17982.586425] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[17982.586426] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | line
[17982.586427] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[17982.586429] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[17982.586430] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[17982.586431] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[17982.586432] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[17982.586434] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp3
[17982.586435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version
[17982.586436] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[17982.586437] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[17982.586439] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[17982.586440] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[17982.586441] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[17982.586442] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[17982.586444] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[17982.586445] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[17982.586446] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr_pref
[17982.586447] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[17982.586449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[17982.586450] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[17982.586451] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[17982.586453] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[17982.586454] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[17982.586455] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[17982.586456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[17982.586623] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: nothing in log
[17982.586632] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Command REPLY_RXON failed: FW Error
[17982.586633] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error clearing ASSOC_MSK on BSS (-5)
[17982.829267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17983.130930] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17983.232123] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17988.417653] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[17988.417665] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[17988.417669] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[17988.418017] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 00828086 00100506 02800034 00000008 f7d00004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418023] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 13218086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 0000010b
[17988.418029] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418034] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000060: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418039] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000080: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418044] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418050] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000000 0081e005 fee003f8 00000000 00000000
[17988.418056] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 000000e0: 00010010 10008ec0 00100800 0006ec11 10110042 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418061] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000100: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00062011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000140: 00010003 ff19b4e8 e09d31ff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418076] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[17988.418146] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 00488700 00000040 08000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000030 00000000
[17988.418158] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000001 080403c5 000000b0 00000000 90000001 00030001 80008040 00080046
[17988.418170] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[17988.418233] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00062011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418243] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418256] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.1) config registers:
[17988.418490] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000000: 1e128086 00100407 060400c4 00810010 00000000 00000000 00020200 000000f0
[17988.418496] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000020: f7d0f7d0 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0012020b
[17988.418502] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000040: 01428010 00008000 00100000 02123c12 70110042 000cb200 01400000 00000000
[17988.418507] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000060: 00000000 00000016 00000000 00000000 00010002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418513] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000080: 00019005 fee00278 00000000 00000000 0000a00d 05341028 00000000 00000000
[17988.418518] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000000a0: c8020001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418524] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000b02 81118000 00000000
[17988.418529] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000000e0: 00000300 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 08050f87 00000000
[17988.418534] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000100: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418540] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418545] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418550] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000160: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418555] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000180: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418560] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000001a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418565] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000001c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418571] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 000001e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418574] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000200: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[17988.418585] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[17988.430897] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[17988.430944] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[17988.431060] Modules linked in: ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel iwldvm snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mac80211 snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep libarc4 kvm_intel snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlwifi i915 snd_seq dell_laptop crct10dif_pclmul ledtrig_audio crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer drm_kms_helper aesni_intel mei_me snd mei cfg80211 drm dell_smm_hwmon aes_x86_64 crypto_simd soundcore dell_wmi dell_smbios dcdbas cryptd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt dell_wmi_descriptor dell_smo8800 dell_rbtn sparse_keymap joydev intel_cstate input_leds intel_rapl_perf mac_hid serio_raw wmi_bmof sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 sdhci_pci ahci cqhci psmouse sdhci i2c_i801 libahci lpc_ich e1000e wmi video
[17988.431706] Modules linked in: ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel iwldvm snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mac80211 snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep libarc4 kvm_intel snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlwifi i915 snd_seq dell_laptop crct10dif_pclmul ledtrig_audio crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer drm_kms_helper aesni_intel mei_me snd mei cfg80211 drm dell_smm_hwmon aes_x86_64 crypto_simd soundcore dell_wmi dell_smbios dcdbas cryptd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt dell_wmi_descriptor dell_smo8800 dell_rbtn sparse_keymap joydev intel_cstate input_leds intel_rapl_perf mac_hid serio_raw wmi_bmof sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 sdhci_pci ahci cqhci psmouse sdhci i2c_i801 libahci lpc_ich e1000e wmi video
[17988.432358] Modules linked in: ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel iwldvm snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mac80211 snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep libarc4 kvm_intel snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlwifi i915 snd_seq dell_laptop crct10dif_pclmul ledtrig_audio crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer drm_kms_helper aesni_intel mei_me snd mei cfg80211 drm dell_smm_hwmon aes_x86_64 crypto_simd soundcore dell_wmi dell_smbios dcdbas cryptd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt dell_wmi_descriptor dell_smo8800 dell_rbtn sparse_keymap joydev intel_cstate input_leds intel_rapl_perf mac_hid serio_raw wmi_bmof sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 sdhci_pci ahci cqhci psmouse sdhci i2c_i801 libahci lpc_ich e1000e wmi video
[17988.539148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[17988.843033] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating/downgrading your kernel version.

Another thing that comes in mind, are you using any of the power-saving tools like tlp, tuned, powertop?

Comment: I add some new code from terminal, after Wireless stopped working.